# SQL Server insert performance

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulkinsert

I have an insert query that gets generated like this

```
INSERT INTO InvoiceDetail (LegacyId,InvoiceId,DetailTypeId,Fee,FeeTax,Investigatorid,SalespersonId,CreateDate,CreatedById,IsChargeBack,Expense,RepoAgentId,PayeeName,ExpensePaymentId,AdjustDetailId) 
VALUES(1,1,2,1500.0000,0.0000,163,1002,'11/30/2001 12:00:00 AM',1116,0,550.0000,850,NULL,@ExpensePay1,NULL); 
DECLARE @InvDetail1 INT; SET @InvDetail1 = (SELECT @@IDENTITY);
```

This query is generated for only 110K rows.

It takes 30 minutes for all of these query's to execute

I checked the query plan and the largest % nodes are

A Clustered Index Insert at 57% query cost
which has a long xml that I don't want to post.

A Table Spool which is 38% query cost

```
<RelOp AvgRowSize="35" EstimateCPU="5.01038E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" NodeId="80" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0466109">
  <OutputList>
    <ColumnReference Database="[SkipPro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[InvoiceDetail]" Column="InvoiceId" />
    <ColumnReference Database="[SkipPro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[InvoiceDetail]" Column="InvestigatorId" />
    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1054" />
    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1055" />
  </OutputList>
  <Spool PrimaryNodeId="3" />
</RelOp>
```

So my question is what is there that I can do to improve the speed of this thing? I already run 
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME NOCHECK CONSTRAINTS ALL
Before the queries and then 
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME NOCHECK CONSTRAINTS ALL
after the queries.

And that didn't shave off hardly anything off of the time.

Know I am running these queries in a .NET application that uses a SqlCommand object to send the query.

I then tried to output the sql commands to a file and then execute it using sqlcmd, but I wasn't getting any updates on how it was doing, so I gave up on that.

Any ideas or hints or help?

UPDATE:

Ok so all of you were very helpful. In this situation I wish I could give credit to more than one answer.

The solution to fix this was twofold.

The first:

1) I disabled/reenabled all the foreign keys(much easier than dropping them)

```
ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

2) I disabled/Reenabled the indexes (again much easier than dropping)

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_InvoiceDetail_1] ON [dbo].[InvoiceDetail] DISABLE
ALTER INDEX [IX_InvoiceDetail_1] ON [dbo].[InvoiceDetail] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, ONLINE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF )
```

The second:

I wrapped all of the insert statements into one transaction. I initially didn't know how to do that in .NET.

I really appreciate all of the input I got.

If I ever do this kind of translation from DB to DB I will definitely start with BULK INSERT. It seems much more flexible and faster.

Comment: Tell us more about your clustered index and the insert.  Does your insert relate to your clustered index such that all records will be appended after existing records?  (ie, the records are naturally sequential to the clustered index)

Comment: Never use @@Identity! YOu can mess up data integrity big time with this as it will not always return the correct value. Use scope_Identity() instead.

Comment: I know this is old but do you remember how much time the final queries took? Just wondering how much of a difference this all made?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like the inserts are causing SQL Server to recalculate the indexes. One *possible* solution would be to drop the index, perform the insert, and re-add the index. With your attempted solution, even if you tell it to ignore constraints, it will still need to keep the index updated.

Answer (score 11):

Most likely this is commit flush wait. If you don't wrap sets of INSERTs into explicitly managed transaction then  each INSERT is its own auto-committed transaction. Meaning each INSERT issues automatically a commit, and a commit has to wait until the log is durable (ie. written to disk). Flushing the log after each insert is extremely slow.

For instance, trying to insert 100k rows like yours on a single row commit style:

```
set nocount on; 
declare @start datetime = getutcdate();  

declare @i int = 0;
while @i < 100000
begin
INSERT INTO InvoiceDetail (
  LegacyId,InvoiceId,DetailTypeId,Fee,
  FeeTax,Investigatorid,SalespersonId,
  CreateDate,CreatedById,IsChargeBack,
  Expense,RepoAgentId,PayeeName,ExpensePaymentId,
  AdjustDetailId) 
  VALUES(1,1,2,1500.0000,0.0000,163,1002,
    '11/30/2001 12:00:00 AM',
    1116,0,550.0000,850,NULL,1,NULL); 
  set @i = @i+1;
end

select datediff(ms, @start, getutcdate());
```

This runs in about 12seconds on my server. But adding transaction management and committing every 1000 rows the insert of 100k rows lasts only about 4s:

```
set nocount on;  
declare @start datetime = getutcdate();  

declare @i int = 0;
begin transaction
while @i < 100000
begin
INSERT INTO InvoiceDetail (
  LegacyId,InvoiceId,DetailTypeId,
  Fee,FeeTax,Investigatorid,
  SalespersonId,CreateDate,CreatedById,
  IsChargeBack,Expense,RepoAgentId,
  PayeeName,ExpensePaymentId,AdjustDetailId) 
  VALUES(1,1,2,1500.0000,0.0000,163,1002,
    '11/30/2001 12:00:00 AM',
    1116,0,550.0000,850,NULL,1,NULL); 
  set @i = @i+1;
  if (@i%1000 = 0)
  begin
    commit
    begin transaction
  end  
end
commit;
select datediff(ms, @start, getutcdate());
```

Also given that I can insert 100k rows in 12 seconds even w/o the batch commit, while you need 30 minutes, its worth investigating 1) the speed of your IO subsystem (eg. what `Avg. Sec per Transaction` you see on the drives) and 2) what else is the client code doing between retrieving the @@identity from one call and invoking the next insert. It could be that the bulk of time is in the client side of the stack. One simple solution would be to launch multiple inserts in parallel (BeginExecuteNonQuery) so you feed the SQL Server inserts constantly.

Comment: Your load runs entirely on the database server. I think he is sending his inserts one at a time over the wire and that's why they are slow. Probably more due to the network latency and round trips than the actual commit flush overhead.

Comment: I just ran what I think is a reasonable reproduction of his 110K insert statements, one by one, over the wire, and yes starting a transaction first increases the throughput by an order of magnitude!

Comment: @RalphShillington with SQL Server 2014 and later you also have the alternative of [lazy durability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449490.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

Are you executing these queries one at a time from a .Net client (i.e. sending 110,000 separate query requests to SQL Server)?

In that case, it's likely that it's the network latency and other overhead of sending these INSERTs to the SQL Server without batching them, not SQL Server itself.

Check out BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 6):

You have tagged this question as "bulkinsert". So why not use the [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command?

If you want progress updates you can split the bulk insert into smaller pieces and update the progress after each piece completes.

Comment: Does Bulk insert allow you to enter identity columns? I must admit i don't know too much about bulk insert, i am researching it though.

Comment: @Jose: I think this article answers your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx

Answer (score 6):

There are a several things you can do:

```
1) Disable any triggers on this table
2) Drop all indexes
3) Drop all foreign keys
4) Disable any check constraints
```

Answer (score 5):

Running individual INSERTs is always going to be the slowest option.  Also - what's the deal with the @@IDENTITY - doesn't look like you ned to keep track of those in between.

If you don't want to use BULK INSERT from file or SSIS, there is a [SqlBulkCopy feature in ADO.NET](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/03/08/2877.aspx) which would probably be your best bet if you absolutely have to do this from within a .NET program.

110k rows should take less time to import than me reseaching and writing this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions for increasing insert performance:

- Increase ADO.NET BatchSize
- Choose the target table's clustered index wisely, so that inserts won't lead to clustered index node splits (e.g. autoinc column)
- Insert into a temporary heap table first, then issue one big "insert-by-select" statement to push all that staging table data into the actual target table
- Apply SqlBulkCopy
- Place a table lock before inserting (if your business scenario allows for it)

Taken from [Tips For Lightning-Fast Insert Performance On SqlServer](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.com/2011/10/tips-for-lightning-fast-insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, let it run, check performance counters. what do you see? What disc layout do you have? I can insert some million rows in 30 minutes - nearly a hundred million rows, to be exact (real time financial information, linkes to 3 other tables). I pretty much bet that your IO layout is bad (i.e. bad disc structure, bad file distribution)