# Storing objects async with NHibernate,Performance tests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, nhibernate

The current case is a pretty complicated but i can tare it down to this.
I Have 300k objects (or more,the number is just for the statistics)in a ConcurrentQueue<> ,and these objects are ready to be stored in the database. Im using several threads, to do the writing in the database.Every thread does the following while the queue is not empty:

1. if can dequeue
2. take  an object
3. open a session
4. open a transaction
5. persist the object
6. commit the transaction
7. close the session
8. go to 1.

After some testing there are the results

- 2 threads persits 300k objects for 00:00:49.4008256 averege time
- 4 threads persits 300k objects for 00:00:29.6146939 averege time
- 10 threads persits 300k objects for 00:00:24.0903779 averege time
- 20 threads persits 300k objects for 00:00:19.7451293 averege time
- 40 threads persits 300k objects for 00:00:18.2760453 averege time

And here goes my questions:
[1] Why when i am doubling the number of threads the execution time is not halved?
 
[2] And is there anyway of improving this without increasing the number of objects in the transaction.
I am using **NHibernate with MSSQL 2012**.

Comment: Hope that's not a real `goto`!

Comment: lol,no im using while(toBePersisted.TryDequeue(out obj))

Comment: Simple answer is don't use NHibernate for this task. You can try stateless session to speed up but I would use the right tool for the job. Something like SQLBulkCopy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your Question 
**[1] Why when i am doubling the number of threads the execution time is not halved?**
There is not necessary that when you increase the thread you can finish your work early.

 And the reason for it can be any thing like available memory, or other resource are less to run your application. It is OS which will decide all this.

Comment: I can explain it in deep if needed but bottom line is that doubling a thread is not give you guarantee that it will reduce your time, it all about available resources

Answer (score 1):

You may be doubling the number of threads, but you're just moving the bottleneck to the SQL server instance. You haven't doubled the resources that needs to do the same work in half the time.

I'd like to see the code for the thread if possible, can't think of any advise without.

Comment: The code is pretty straight forward,nothing complicated -a shared instance of ConccurentQueue<> and a number of threads serving it.
About the mssql resources - any tips about how to do that?

Comment: Look at the physical resources on the server, what is being hammered? Memory, processor, network? Then you have to scale up the resource that is under presure, e.g. install more RAM. Might also be worth looking at SQL profiler to see if the inserts are slow, then if they are, maybe there are reasons for that, unnessasary indexes you could drop to speed up inserts. Check this out on slow inserts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2457862/360211

Comment: Do you absolutely have to have 1 object per transaction? I think you know this would help alot. Bult inserts, presuming NHibernate would use them, are way faster than singles.

Comment: It would be best if a there is a single object per transaction.